# Ubuntu One is not starting

Tags: ubuntu-one, language-support, locale

I am using Ubuntu in Turkish and when click on Ubuntu One, it does not start. However when using Ubuntu in English it works. So I want Ubuntu One to work in Turkish Ubuntu. What should I do?

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/467397) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely experiencing [bug #467397](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/467397). A possible workaround is described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/467397/comments/8):

> As far as I was able to test this bug, the locale change is required
>   for ubuntuone-client-applet (OAuth module), not syncdaemon. Syncdaemon
>   is able to sync files with tr_TR locale.
>
> Open gnome-session-properties, select "Ubuntu One" entry, Edit it and
>   prefix the available command with `env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`, so that
>   Command (Komut) is `env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 ubuntuone-client-applet`
>
> The client will be started with English/USA locale on next login.
>   This is still a workaround but at least it will not require manual
>   syncdaemon/applet startup with en_US locale.

Comment: Thank you but but is still not working.